# Binary Output from Google Script HMAC encription

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, hmac, amazon-cloudwatch

I am current working with Google Apps script and am attempting to write & sign an HTTP request to AWS CloudWatch.

On the Amazon API documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-calculate-signature.html) regarding how to create a signing key, they use pseudo to explain that the HMAC algorithm is to return binary format.

```
HMAC(key, data) represents an HMAC-SHA256 function 
that returns output in binary format.
```

Google apps script offers a method to do such a hash,

```
Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,
                                            data,
                                            key);
```

but the return type is always a byte array.

```
Byte[]
```

How do I convert the Byte[] to the binary data AWS wants? Or is there a vanilla javascript function I can use in Google Apps Script to compute the hash?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried converting to String first (from Byte[]) and then, converting it to Binary would be easier?

Comment: Yes I, have tried that by converting the Byte[] to a blob and then reading the data as string to be passed into the next iteration of hashing, but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from byte array to the binary data required should be simple:

```
kDate = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,
             '20130618', 'AWS4' + kSecret);
kDate = Utilities.newBlob(kDate).getDataAsString();
kRegion = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, 
             'eu-west-1', kDate);
```

BUT you have to look onto [this open issue in the bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2227) - there could be some issues in conversion.

maybe you could try to make a String.fromCharCode() loop and avoid negative numers:

```
kDateB = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256,
             '20130618', 'AWS4' + kSecret);
kDate = '';
for (var i=0; i<kDateB.length; i++)
  kDate += String.fromCharCode(kDateB[i]<0?256+kDateB[i]:0+kDateB[i]);
kRegion = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_256, 
             'eu-west-1', kDate);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is definitely frustrating. I made a comment on the bugtracker, so hopefully this will get the google team to at least respond and give an update to this known issue.

Comment: did you try the ´String.fromCharCode` option? The problem seems to appear with negative Byte values. Adding 256 to these should solve the problem.

Comment: I did try to do this and get rid of negative values by adding 256, but unfortunately I am still getting the incorrect result. Google has said that this is a known issue and is working on it, but they have also stated that there is no update to this bug at the current time.

Comment: I managed to get the signature to work, but only by using CryptoJS which I imported into Google Script by copy and pasting the raw javascript code, but I still haven't managed to get pure Google code to work.

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure it is a bug that Utilities.computeHmacSignature take key as an ASCII. But there was no way to parse byte[] to ASCII correctly in GAS

And the library writer is too stupid too just provide function which take key as byte[]

So I use this instead : http://caligatio.github.com/jsSHA/

Just copy SHA.js and SHA-256.js then it work fine

PS. it waste my time for whole 2 days so I'm very annoying