# Google Apps script equivalent of PHP's hash_hmac() with RAW BINARY output?

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, base64, hmac

I have to connect to an API using hash_hmac. In the PHP documentation for hash_hmac, the fourth parameter bool $raw_output controls whether the output is raw binary data (true) or lowercase hexits (false). My program works in PHP by simply setting that parameter to true.

This is what works in PHP:

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA256', $signature_string, $private_key, true))
```

In Google Apps I can't use any javascript libraries (or can I?) but there is this function: Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsha256signaturevalue-key

However this doesn't have the "true" option that PHP has, so it doesn't output the raw binary data.

How can I get the same value using Google Apps as I get in PHP?

This is what I have in Google Apps, but obviously it doesn't output the raw binary data:

```
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(signature_string, private_key);
```

I did find a way to convert the response to hex (PHP equivalent of FALSE instead of TRUE, but that's not bringing me any closer to the solution.

```
// convert to hex 
var signature_in_hex = signature.reduce(function(str,chr) {
chr = (chr < 0 ? chr + 256 : chr).toString(16);
return str + (chr.length==1?'0':'') + chr;
},'');
```

Comment: Perhaps posting some example output from both PHP and GAppScript would help us figure out the issue?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but does feeding the byte array generated by `Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature()` into `Utilities.newBlob()` do what you need?

Comment: Although, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160896/binary-output-from-google-script-hmac-encription?rq=1 would suggest that it's not the solution...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is just copying these scripts straight into Google Apps:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js

And then use:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, private_key);
var base64 = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/c5r78fzm/